# Setting the Virtual Try-on glasses model in the correct position and making it follow face movements

Tags: three.js, 3d, computer-vision, augmented-reality, mediapipe

I'm working on a project where I want to try on a 3D glasses model in real time. The problem is I'm unable to set the model in its right position, and it does not follow face movements. I have successfully detected the face using Mediapipe, and it works fine.

Here's the code I implemented for this function:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.104.0/build/three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.104.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.104.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

// Get the webcam video element
const webcamElement = document.getElementById('webcam');
// Get the Three.js rendering container
const container = document.getElementById('scene-container');
// Variable to track the video state
let isVideo = false;
let glassesModel;
let eyesDetected = false;

// Check if the webcam element is present
if (!webcamElement) {
    console.error("Webcam element not found.");
}

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.getElementById('webgl-canvas').appendChild(canvas);

// Set alpha to true for a transparent background
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0); // Set background color to transparent
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(4, 5, 11);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

const groundGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20, 32, 32);
groundGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
const groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0x555555,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5
});
const groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeometry, groundMaterial);
scene.add(groundMesh);

const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 3, 100, 0.2, 0.5);
spotLight.position.set(0, 25, 0);
scene.add(spotLight);

function loadGlassesModel() {
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('/static/models/sport_glasses_b307/scene.gltf', (gltf) => {
        const mesh = gltf.scene;
        mesh.position.set(0, 2, 2);

        const scaleFactor = 0.04; // Adjust this value as needed
        mesh.scale.set(scaleFactor, 0.05, scaleFactor);

        scene.add(mesh);
    });
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
controls.screenSpacePanning = false;
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;

animate();

// Async function to start the webcam
async function startWebcam() {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
    webcamElement.srcObject = stream;

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        webcamElement.onloadedmetadata = () => {
            resolve();
        };
    });

    isVideo = true;
    await new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));

    loadGlassesModel();
}

// Handle webcam switch state change
$("#webcam-switch").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        startWebcam();
    } else {
        stopWebcam();
    }
});

// Function to stop the webcam
function stopWebcam() {
    if (isVideo) {
        webcamElement.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        isVideo = false;
        console.log("Webcam stopped");
    }
}

// Async function to capture and send the image to Django
async function captureAndSendToDjango() {
    if (isVideo && webcamElement) {
        try {
            const imageData = await webcamToImageData(webcamElement);
            console.log("Image data:", imageData);
            await sendImageToDjango(imageData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error capturing and sending image to Django:", error);
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(captureAndSendToDjango);
}

// Async function to convert webcam data to image data
async function webcamToImageData(webcamElement) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = webcamElement.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = webcamElement.videoHeight;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(webcamElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const base64data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').split(',')[1];
        resolve(base64data);
    });
}

// Function to draw landmarks on the canvas
function drawLandmarks(response) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('facemesh-canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    const landmarksArray = response.landmarks;
    if (landmarksArray && landmarksArray.length > 0) {
        context.fillStyle = 'red';

        const cameraOffsetX = 0;
        const cameraOffsetY = 0;

        let leftEyeLandmarks;
        let rightEyeLandmarks;

        for (const landmarkList of landmarksArray) {
            for (const landmark of landmarkList) {
                const x = landmark[0] + cameraOffsetX;
                const y = landmark[1] + cameraOffsetY;

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(x, y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                context.fill();

                console.log(`Eye coordinates: x=${x}, y=${y}`);

                if (landmark[5] && landmark[5] === 'left_eye') {
                    leftEyeLandmarks = landmarkList;
                } else if (landmark[5] && landmark[5] === 'right_eye') {
                    rightEyeLandmarks = landmarkList;
                }
            }
        }

        if (leftEyeLandmarks && rightEyeLandmarks) {
            console.log("Eyes detected!");
            eyesDetected = true;

            const averageEyePosition = [
                (leftEyeLandmarks[3][0] + rightEyeLandmarks[0][0]) / 2,
                (leftEyeLandmarks[3][1] + rightEyeLandmarks[0][1]) / 2,
            ];

            if (glassesModel) {
                glassesModel.position.set(
                    (averageEyePosition[0] + cameraOffsetX) * scaleFactorX,
                    (averageEyePosition[1] + cameraOffsetY) * scaleFactorY,
                    -5
                );

                if (loadGlassesModel) {
                    loadGlassesModel.visible = eyesDetected;
                }
            }
        } else {
            eyesDetected = false;
            if (glassesModel) {
                glassesModel.visible = false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.error("No landmarks found in the response.");
    }
}

// Async function to send the image to Django via AJAX
```

I'm facing issues with setting the glasses model in the correct position and making it follow face movements. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.